# The most simple RNN with the most simple application?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I want an application to testify my own RNN.

I just write the most simple RNN myself **without** tensorflow.

So I need a simple application of the RNN to make sure that the implementation is right. The simpler the better.

For example, I could use MNIST to testify my own CNN.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

See a simple RNN model

```
def model(X, W, B, lstm_size):
    # X, input shape: (batch_size, time_step_size, input_vec_size)
    XT = tf.transpose(X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute time_step_size and batch_size
    # XT shape: (time_step_size, batch_size, input_vec_size)
    XR = tf.reshape(XT, [-1, lstm_size]) # each row has input for each lstm cell (lstm_size=input_vec_size)
    # XR shape: (time_step_size * batch_size, input_vec_size)
    X_split = tf.split(0, time_step_size, XR) # split them to time_step_size (28 arrays)
    # Each array shape: (batch_size, input_vec_size)

    # Make lstm with lstm_size (each input vector size)
    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)

    # Get lstm cell output, time_step_size (28) arrays with lstm_size output: (batch_size, lstm_size)
    outputs, _states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm, X_split, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation
    # Get the last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], W) + B, lstm.state_size # State size to initialize the stat
```

You can find more examples from https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/.